# クラスのメンバ変数の初期化が知りたい。

Tags: c#

C#のクラスのメンバの代入ではない初期化の方法が知りたいです。
c++でいう`class C():t(5),a(3){  }`などいった代入ではない初期化はC#ではどうやるのでしょうか？
１、クラスの中で初期化することは初期化でしょうか？

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;

        class Sample
        {
        //    public int x;
        //    public int y;
        //    public string name;

            public int x = 10;
            public int y = 20;
            public string name = "未設定";


            public Sample()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("引数なし");

            }

            //public Sample() : this(1, 2, "確認")
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine("引数なしthis");

            //}

            //public Sample(int x,int y,string name)
            //{
            //    this.x = x;
            //    this.y = y;
            //    this.name = name;
            //    Console.WriteLine("引数あり");


            //}

        }

        class Program
        {    
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {        

                //Sample t = new Sample{1,2,"aa" };
                Sample t = new Sample();

                Console.WriteLine(t.x);
                Console.WriteLine(t.y);
                Console.WriteLine(t.name);




                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class C():t(5),a(3){  }`というスタイルの初期化はC#にはありません。

```
    class Sample
    {
        public int x = 10;

        public Sample()
        {
        }
```

の様にメンバ変数に初期値を代入して書いた場合、

```
    class Sample
    {
        public int x;

        public Sample()
        {
            x=10;
        }
```

とコンパイルされ、コンストラクタの先頭で代入が実施されます。
（thisで複数回自クラスのコンストラクタを呼ぶ時は、１回しか実行されないように制御してくれてたと思います）

なので「クラスの中で初期化することは初期化」であると思います。